# routing and integration testing webapi via selfhosting

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am using this code:

```
[Fact]
public void ValueController_WithGetMethos_ShouldReturnValidData_NoBaseClass()
{
    var configuration = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:64466");
    configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
    configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), new WebApiClassBase.TestAssemblyResolver(typeof(ValuesController)));

            configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(configuration);
    try
    {
    server.OpenAsync().Wait();

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost:64466/api/values"),
        Method = HttpMethod.Get
    };

    var client = new HttpClient(server);
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result)
    {
        response.Should().Not.Be.Null();
        response.IsSuccessStatusCode.Should().Be.True();

        string[] result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string[]>().Result;

        result.Length.Should().Be.EqualTo(4);
        result[0].Should().Be.EqualTo("http://tostring.it");
        result[1].Should().Be.EqualTo("http://imperugo.tostring.it");
        result[2].Should().Be.EqualTo("http://twitter.com/imperugo");
        result[3].Should().Be.EqualTo("http://www.linkedin.com/in/imperugo");
    }
    }
    finally
    {
    configuration.Dispose();
    server.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Inspired by [this](https://github.com/imperugo/Spike/blob/master/imperugo.webapi.selfhost/imperugo.webapi.integrationTest/ValuesControllerWithoutBaseClass.cs), which also contains the relevant [ValuesController](https://github.com/imperugo/Spike/blob/master/imperugo.webapi.selfhost/imperugo.webapi.selfhost/Controller/ValuesController.cs). I have noticed that I had to adapt the routing:

```
configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

according to the one in my WebApiConfig. However, when I try to access an Action with attribute routing like this:

```
Route("Calculator/AddTwoNumbers/a/{a}/b/{a}")]
public IHttpActionResult AddTwoNumbers(PayLoad payLoad)
```

I get an 404 - Not found error. Do I also have to define this declarative routing? If so, integration testing seems quite tedious. Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

PS:

I tried:

```
configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

which does not seem to help

Comment: Did you `MapHttpAttributeRoutes` before or after you added the default route? (you need to do it before)

Comment: thanks for the comment. after.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed it, please write an answer if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup AttributeRouting before your default route is configured.

```
configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Routes are evaluated in the order they are added to the `RouteCollection`. If your Default route comes first, then it will match incoming routes before your Attribute Routes have a chance to be matched.